# vpn ibm-cloud Cannot get to private addresses via VPN

Tags: ecm

Apparently Softlayer changed the VPN. So I've reinstalled my MotionPro client on Win10 and can now connect. But I can no longer connect to the 10 addresses beyond it. They don't show up in the netstat -rn listing.

I can ping the remote end of the VPN, but not the 10 addresses. What else do I need to do to make this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No worries. It turned out the VPN entry point has changed, and when I use a different one it now gives me all the correct routing.